# Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in linux when csv file uploading

Tags: mysql

i am new in linux .
 when i am uploading data from csv file it is displaying error like this

Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

1045

(i display this error by mysql_error() function)

i am not importing file by php myadmin  i am uploading file by input tag

how should do?

Answer (score 0):

Either the user `apache@localhost` doesn't exist on your MySQL server, or the password you are using is wrong. Either way, you need to set up the security on your Mysql server properly.

There's a tutorial on creating MySQL users [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-create-user.aspx)